# How to setup local MQTT in Bridge REMAP remote topics

Tags: mqtt, publish-subscriber

I am trying to setup MQTT bridge, where I want to publish all local topic to remote, but subscribe only certain remote topic which matches wild card and remap to local broker

Here is the config

```
 topic # out 2 "" UP/site1/
 topic DOWN/site1/# in 2 DOWN/ DOWN/site1/
```

local to remote publishing works perfectly, but remote to local mapping doesn't works.

I just want to pull topics with prefix `DOWN/site1/#` from remote to local broker and remove the prefix `DOWN/site1/`.

I am using cloudmqtt.com as remote and local MQTT (bridge) running on Raspberry Pi Zero.

Any help here ?

Answer (score 3):

You want something like this for the last line:

```
topic # in 2 "" Down/site1/
```

This is because the first topic is relative to the last remote topic prefix.

The following example from the mosquitto docs will hopefully make it clearer:

> The configuration below connects a bridge to the broker at
>   test.mosquitto.org. It subscribes to the remote topic
>   `$SYS/broker/clients/total` and republishes the messages received to the
>   local topic `test/mosquitto/org/clients/total`
>
> ```
> connection test-mosquitto-org
> address test.mosquitto.org
> cleansession true
> topic clients/total in 0 test/mosquitto/org $SYS/broker/
> ```